# Creating variables from register in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have the register variable which contains number of lines in stdout_lines. With those lines I have to create variables. Is there any workaround for this.

Ex: `register variable : output`

`output.stdout_line` contains below lines

```
variable1: value1; 
variable2: variable1 + value2; 
variable3: variable2 + value3; 
.
.
.
.
n number of lines (change based on the output);
```

I Need to create variables with name `variable1` and assign `value1` to it and create variable with name `variable2` and assign `variable1's value and value 2` to it and so on upto n number of lines.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I was stucked in after got the stdout_lines

Comment: Whatever it is you're doing, dump it to a file instead of `stdout`.  Then read the file with the `include_vars` module: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_vars_module.html

Comment: @jack is there any other way to do this? because I need to do this in target machine and i should not create files everytime when I am running the playbook

Comment: Might be able to come up with something much uglier.  Just write the file and then delete it when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, the easy way is to send the output to a file and load the file.  Parsing stdout is a little harder, but this should work:

```
  - set_fact:
      "{{ item | regex_search('^[^:]*') }}": " {{ item | regex_search('[^:]*$') }}"
    with_items: "{{ output.stdout_lines }}"
```

Comment: Thanx jack let me try this

Comment: Obviously, it's not going to work for more complicated data.